# Mass update prices of Magento in a specific category?

Tags: magento

For now what I have for updating prices of all products in my Magento store is this snippet:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
    ;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->setPrice(round($product->getPrice() - 1000.00));
    $product->setSpecialPrice(round($product->getSpecialPrice() - 1000.00));
    $product->save();
}
```

My question is how to update all the products in a **specific category** rather than entire store? I guess there should be some more selectors such as ->addCategoryToSelect() or something but never found any documentations regarding this.

Please enlighten me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the way I would do it. You can get a collection of products directly from the category. I am not 100% sure you actually need the round function, but if you do decide to use it, I would make sure that you put parenthesis around the $product->getPrice() - 1000 just to be sure it is being calculated before it is sent to the function. I opted to not include it in my answer because I do not think you need it.

Give this a try:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load($category_id)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach($products as $product) {
    $product->setPrice(($product->getPrice() - 1000)));
    $product->setSpecialPrice(($product->getSpecialPrice() - 1000)));
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: I do want to say that I feel it is important to make sure you do the addAttributeToSelect('*'). I have seen it happen where other parts of the product gets changed if it is not included in the model when loaded. Specifically visibility. It would change to its default value if not included when loading the model. Just something to keep an eye out for.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                       ->addCategoryFilter($category);

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    $product->setPrice(round($product->getPrice() - 1000.00));
    $product->setSpecialPrice(round($product->getSpecialPrice() - 1000.00));
    $product->save();
}
```

Best of luck.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. All the product prices are now -1000

Comment: I did. Sorry I meant all the product prices of the designated category are now -100.

Comment: So it did update __for the category__ as you wanted/stated by your  question. It's probably your setPrice function you would need changed instead.

Comment: Well it ruined all the prices. Not to blame you but just wanted to know why your code didn't work. $product->getPrice() didn't seem to return the prices so all the prices was changed to -100 instead.

Comment: You seem to be setting the price to [special_price - 1000]. Are you sure that's what you want to do?  Maybe that's why the prices are not set to what you want them set to.